# How to prevent AttributeError for undeclared variables and methods and fix __getattr__ method call multiple times?

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = 1
         self.c = 0
     def __getattr__(self, name):
         self.c += 1
         print('getattribute')
         if hasattr(self, name) is False:
             print("No")
             return None
         return super(Foo, self).__getattr__(self, name)

fo = Foo()
print(fo.a)
print(fo.b)
print(fo.c)
```

Running the above programs prints "getattribute" and "no" multiple times. `__getattr__` is called multiple times. 333 to be exact. `self.c` prints 333.

What I want to achieve is to have a class that doesn't raise an error if a class variable or method is not declared in the class.

Whats the possible reason for this?

Comment: `hasattr` just tries to get the attribute and catches an `AttributeError`. You can use a `try: return super().__getattr__(self, name) except AttributeError: return None`. That can potentially hide other `AttributeError`s, but it’s difficult to avoid doing that just by the nature of Python.

Comment: Create singleton class.

Comment: @Ryan thanks. Your solution works. It turns out hasattr calls getattr internally. But wouldn't this should have resulted into an infinite loop? Why 333 calls only?

Comment: @MishaVacic How that would solve the issue and help me achieve no `AttributeError` class?

Comment: @Ryan can you add your comment as an answer and explain the questions in my comment so that I can mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hasattr` just tries to get the attribute and returns `False` if it can’t. Whether it can’t is determined in Python 3 by an attempt throwing an `AttributeError`, and in Python 2 by an attempt throwing *any* error. (This includes `RecursionError`s and is why it fails silently after 333 calls. Python 2 is not a sane language; upgrade to 3 if possible.)

Instead, you can return the alternative value on an `AttributeError` yourself:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        return super(Foo, self).__getattr__(self, name)
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

This can potentially hide other `AttributeError`s, but it’s difficult to avoid doing that just by the nature of Python.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for Python3. Unfortunately, can't use Python 3 for this project(organizations project). I will mark this answer.

Comment: @AmitTripathi: The original code works on Python 2. `__getattribute__` wouldn’t be right for something overriding `__getattr__`.

Comment: yes it works but not in the way you would expect.
The above code raises `AttributeError 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'` in Python 2 because `object` doesn't have `__getattr__` in Python 2.
So my edit was correct!

Comment: @AmitTripathi: That’s fine, though, since it will catch the `AttributeError` for `__getattr__` as well if it doesn’t exist later in the MRO.

Comment: But in Python 2 the code is equal to `def __getattr__(self, name): return None` :)

Comment: @AmitTripathi: Right, but only if you’re inheriting from `object` or something else that doesn’t implement `__getattr__`. (If you are and you can guarantee that that will never change, feel free to just `return None` – it will work.)

Comment: Yes, correct this version works even if the class is inherited from some non-object class.

Answer (score 3):

hasattr is a shortcut to call getattr and see if it raises an exception (which means attribute does not exist) or not (which means it exists)

cf : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr

getattr calls __getattr__ so you are doing a recursive call

I think a possible workaround would be to use:

```
name in self.__dict__
```

instead of:

```
hasattr(self, name)
```

Comment: Arount gave the answer

Comment: Yes makes sense. Can you explain why 333 calls not infinite calls?

Answer (score 1):

This is because running `hasattr(self, name)` calls `self.__getattr__(name)` (aka `getattr(self, name)`) - [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr).

So when doing `hasattr(self, name)` within `__getattr__` it calls `self.__getattr__(name)`, here comes the unwanted recursion.

I would fix it with:

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = 1
         self.c = 0
     def __getattr__(self, name):
         self.__dict__['c'] += 1
         print('getattribute')
         try:
             return self.__dict__[name]
         except KeyError:
             print('No')
             return None

fo = Foo()
print(fo.a)
print(fo.b)
print(fo.c)
```

Comment: AFAIK `__getattr__` is only called as a last resort when object is not found anywhere.

Comment: Not true. `fo.c` does **not** call `fo.__getattr__('c')`. https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__

Comment: Yes, just tested it. __getattr__ is not called in case variable is defined either in class or in parent class.

Comment: I think it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from `print(fo.b)`.
Since `b` is not defined as a member of `Foo`, `fo.b` results in a call to `fo.__getattr__('b')`.

Then, `hasattr(self, name)`, which is tantamount to `hasattr(fo, 'b')` calls itself `gettatr(fo, 'b')`, as stated in [hte documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr).

Hence an infinite recursion, resulting in a `RecursionError` in Python 3.

---

Since getting `fo.b` does not really make sense if you know that `Foo` does not have a `b` member, a first fix I would suggest is to define that member.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.b = 1
        ...
```

Your code then outputs

```
1
1
0
```

A more clever fix would be to check if the `name` argument passed to `__getattr__` is `'b'`, or depending to your needs, different from `'a'` and `'c'`.
In this situation, you can force `__getattr__` to define the requested unfound member.

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
    def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name == 'b':
        self.b = 2
        return self.b
    else:
        ...
```

Alternatively:

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
    def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name not in ('a', 'c'):
        self.b = 2
        return self.b
    else:
        ...
```